# Why does a generator function with arguments remember past fetch response

Tags: javascript, iterator, arguments, generator, fetch

While exploring the .js 'generator functions', I have successfully attempted to create a fetch cycle using a generator function. 
I've had a hard time doing it, since the code always failed on the second yield, when trying to parse the response as json.
But, when I passed the data argument back in to the Generator function, everything seemed to be working well, I don't seem to understand why. since the generator function doesn't use the data argument.

Wrong code:

```
const URI = 'some.json';
function* fetchGenerator() {
    const response = yield fetch(URI);
    const json = yield response.json(); //Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
    return json
}
const gen = fetchGenerator();
const fetchSteps = () => {
    const iterator = gen.next();
    if (!iterator.done)
        iterator.value.then((data) => { fetchSteps() });
    else
        document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(iterator.value);

}
fetchSteps();
```

Correct code:

```
const URI = 'some.json';
function* fetchGenerator(data) {
    const response = yield fetch(URI);    
    const json = yield response.json();
    return json
}
const gen = fetchGenerator();
const fetchSteps = (data) => {
    const iterator = gen.next(data);    
    if (!iterator.done)
        iterator.value.then((data) => { fetchSteps(data) });
    else
        document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(iterator.value);

}
fetchSteps();
```

Comment: Why are you even messing around with generators instead of using `async`/`await`?

Comment: just trying to get a better understanding of the whole “generator function” spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't seem to understand why. since the generator function doesn't use the data argument.

Indeed the `data` parameter of the `function* fetchGenerator(data) {` is pointless, but that's not where you are passing in the data anyway. You call the generator function with `fetchGenerator();`.

The promise result `data` is passed to `gen.next(data);`, which is the value that the `yield` expression evaluates to. It is necessary for giving `response` and `json` a value, without which the generator function would not work.

Comment: I’m still confused. If I dont pass the data when calling next, the response forget’s that it is a promise?

Comment: No, `iterator.value` is the promise. `data` is the result of the promise - the thing that you want the `yield` expression to evaluate to. To get `yield` to yield a value, you need to pass that value into `.next()`.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, got it. a bit difficult to get used to the syntax. in a nutshell, when assigning yield to a variable, it's value will be the value of the argument that will be passed in the following .next(argument). if no argument is passed it will be set to undefined. Thnx.
I also recommend this article.
https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators
and have upload a few basic exmples to Git:https://github.com/shaibam/Es6GenertorFunctionExamples